# How to sum 2 joda-time DateTime values (one containing a date and a zero time and another containing a time and a zero date)?

Tags: java, datetime, scala, jodatime

In a Scala 2.8 program of mine I use joda-time with its scala-time wrapper. I've got 2 DateTime values, one for a date (with zero time fields) and one for time (with zero date fields) (the reason of separation is a storage architecture).

How do I get another DateTime value with both date and time parts set from a source pair?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be using `LocalDate` for the date and `LocalTime` for the time. Those are the appropriate types for dates and times respectively. You can get each from a `DateTime` with `DateTime.toLocalDate()` and `DateTime.toLocalTime()` if you *have* to have them as `DateTime` values to start with. Ideally you wouldn't build a `DateTime` at all until you've got both bits separately though :)

Then you can `LocalDate.toDateTime(LocalTime, DateTimeZone)`.

Comment: I don't want LOCAL time. In this project I use strict "Zulu" UTC only.

Comment: @Ivan, `LocalDate is an immutable datetime class representing a date without a time zone.`

Comment: it doesn't work for me, i get this error: value toDateTime is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.Column[com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports.LocalDate]

Comment: @Anna: Well that's not calling `toDateTime` on a `LocalDate` by the looks of it - it's trying to call it on a `Column[LocalDate]`... I don't know Scala and I don't know about the nscala_time wrapper, but `toDateTime` definitely exists on `LocalDate` in Joda Time.